# Extracting a string before a space

Tags: c#

the name Subhajit Sinha is entered in  textbox.
how to extract only Subhajit in one textbox and Sinha in another textbox after clicking the Submit button in the form.

Comment: I am sure that you have tried something before posting this question. Could you demonstrate a reasonable attempt?

Answer (score 4):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<srting> result = textbox.Text.Split().ToList();
```

The result list contains the space delimited string. Now you can use the result list in any format.

Make sure that you point out the memebers of the forum on what you have tried sofar. That way you can learn from your mistakes.